# Are asynchronous actions in Node.js needed only when doing a server application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

For example in the Node.js app I'm writing there's a piece of code along these lines wrapped in an `async` function:

```
await a(param1);
await b(param2);
await c(param3);
await d(param4);
```

As far I understand this would be good if my app were a server, so for example user 1 who sends a request to my server may be at stage `await a(param1);` and maybe this request takes a lot of time, so another user 2 who was at stage `await b(param2);` can still proceed with their request (not having to wait for the resolution of user 1's request).

However if it's only one user using my app I don't see any advantage of using asynchronous code because using `await` turns async code into "sync" because funcion `b` will not proceed until after `a` finished.

Is my understanding correct?

---

EDIT: functions `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` return promises and the next promise depends on the previous.

Comment: the most likely reason that code is written that way is because the functions need to be executed in series, not all at once ... the number of users accessing the server is irrelevant

Comment: @JaromandaX so what is the advantage of using asynchronous code in this example over using synchronous code?

Comment: if functions a-d are asynchronous (which `await` implies) there is no "advantage" or "disadvantage" ... it just **is** - it's almost as if you think `await` makes the function asynchronous ...

Comment: @hitchhiker Consider updating the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that shows asynchronous and synchronous code. I'm not sure that we're on the same page regarding sync and async. That you use `await` doesn't make the app asynchronous automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of asynchronous code is not just allow multiple users to use the application but allow multiple tasks to be performed concurrently with single thread.

If a single user uses the application (e.g. web server), a user may need simultaneous requests. Browsers are able to make simultaneous requests, and they do them. If the code is synchronous and blocking, web server won't respond until synchronous routine is completed.

Even if synchronous control flow is currently suitable for non-web application, there's no guarantee that there won't be a necessity to rewrite it to asynchronous in future. The example is spinner indicator for CLI application.

> However if it's only one user using my app I don't see any advantage of using asynchronous code because using await turns async code into "sync" because funcion b will not proceed until after a finished.

Only if `a`, etc. return promises. Omitting `await` will result in concurrent and uncontrollable promises in this case. In any other case `await` doesn't change how the code works except that introduces one-tick delay.

As another answer mentions, `await` is syntactic sugar for `then`. It doesn't make the code synchronous but performs promise operations in series, similarly to how synchronous code works.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand correctly, there's no time effectiveness gain for single-user app if functions `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` return promises?

Comment: It looks like your original idea about how it works is wrong. In case they return promises, there's no time effectiveness gain for other users regardless of how many users use the app. This is the about the correctness of execution order of a single operation (per each user, if that's more intuitive). If `a`, etc. are non-blocking, they don't prevent multiple users from doing request any way, it doesn't matter whether there's `await` or not. I'd suggest to try using desugared promises instead of `async..await` to understand better how it works.

Comment: If `a`, etc. don't depend on each other then executing them in parallel with `await Promise.all([a(param), ...])` will be more efficient *for current user* because a routine will be completed faster. And if they depend on each other, `Promise.all` will result in incorrect execution order. It's impossible to say more specifically without seeing what `a`, etc. really are.

Comment: I meant that the next promise depends on the previous one. If they don't I understand that using async code will be more effective as you mentioned. But when they do depend on each other then no efficiency is gained for single user. For example for files operation we can usually use sync and async method and there're other examples as well. So as far as I understand efficiency from using promises is only gained when operations don't depend on each other (in the context of single user).

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, 'single user' concept is misleading because you may need concurrent operations even with a single user, e.g. for concurrent browser requests. You won't get benefits from async operations only if it's guaranteed that there are no concurrent operations, e.g. command-line utility that doesn't need realtime indicators and don't do anything that could benefit from concurrency (db requests, simultaneous spawned processes). I personally use sync `fs` only in tools intended for private use.

Comment: In any other case it's a good idea to use async code as a rule of thumb in Node because you may benefit from it at some point. Fortunately, async code is as neat as sync with `async..await`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is my understanding correct?

Not if `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` return promises (implicitly, because they're also `async` functions, or explicitly), which presumably they do if you're using `await` on them. `async`/`await` don't make asynchronous code synchronous (that's impossible), they let you write your code in its *logical* flow rather than its *temporal* flow.

If you remove those `await`s, you'll change the logic of the code: Instead of running `a` to completion, then `b`, then `c`, then `d`, it will *start* all of them and they'll all overlap. So instead of this:

```js
const rnd = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);

const runner = name => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(name + " start");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(name + " end");
    resolve();
  }, rnd())
});

const a = () => runner("a");
const b = () => runner("b");
const c = () => runner("c");
const d = () => runner("d");

(async() => {
  await a();
  await b();
  await c();
  await d();
  console.log("after all calls");
})(); // In real code you'd catch errors
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

you'd get this:

```js
const rnd = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);

const runner = name => new Promise(resolve => {
  console.log(name + " start");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(name + " end");
    resolve();
  }, rnd())
});

const a = () => runner("a");
const b = () => runner("b");
const c = () => runner("c");
const d = () => runner("d");

(async() => {
  a();
  b();
  c();
  d();
  console.log("after all calls");
})(); // In real code you'd catch errors
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That probably isn't what that code is meant to do, regardless of whether it's on a server or in a single-user app.

In terms of using Node.js's various "Sync" methods (`fs.readFileSync` instead of `fs.readFile`, etc.), then yes, if you don't need the Node.js process to do anything else while it's reading the file (e.g., it doesn't have to do any other processing, like handling other requests as a server), you could use those in that single-user app situation.